# Retag request: [windows-server2012r2] -> [windows-server-2012-r2]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

The newly created [windows-server2012r2](/questions/tagged/windows-server2012r2) doesn't match the syntax for other Windows Server tags, such as [windows-server-2008-r2](/questions/tagged/windows-server-2008-r2).

Please retag to [windows-server-2012-r2](/questions/tagged/windows-server-2012-r2).